# Not found .ko when use loadable kernel module in menuconfig

Tags: android-source

Hi i am building kernel for aosp android 13
I have build successfully build build in driver generates .o file
But when i config M in menuconfig and build i don't find any .ko file generated even though loadable kernel module is enabled

Kconfig

```
menuconfig INVCASE
    tristate "Inverse Characters Case"
    default y
```

Makefile

```
obj-$(CONFIG_INVCASE) += invcase.o
invcase-y := invcase.o
```

Add makefile and Kconfig in driver

Makefile

```
+ obj-$(CONFIG_INVCASE)     += invcase/
```

Kconfig

```
source "drivers/invcase/Kconfig"
```

If i build in driver i can get file in /out/common/driver/invcase/invcase.o

Someone can help me
Thank you for everything

I tried with emulator and it works fine but
I can't work on my real board